# Compress 3 ints into a short

Tags: java

So I've got 3 `ints`, 2 of them are only from 0 to 15 (x and z) and 1 (y) goes from 0 to 255. I've been trying to use bit shift with something like this

```
compressed = (short) (x>>12|y>>8|z);
```

but it only gets the z value?

Whats the proper way to do this

Comment: Although bit fields within integral types allow for compact storage, they add complexity to code and can make code fragile and difficult to maintain.  If your data model permits, you should try to use discrete integral types rather than bit fields wherever possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are shifting the wrong direction:

```
compressed = (short) ((x<<12) | (y<<4) | z);
```

Comment: btw `|` has higher precedence than `<<`

Comment: Ive tried testing it with this but it keeps getting duplicates                                                   x=0;y=0;z=0;
  while(x<=15){
   while(y<=255){
    while(z<=15){
     compressed = (short) ((x<<12)|(y << 8) | z);
     System.out.println(compressed);
     z++;
    }
    z=0;
    y++;
   }
   y=0;
   x++;
  }

Comment: I'm pretty sure it should be `(x << 12) | (y << 4) | z`, given that `y` has 8 bits.

Comment: You're right as well. Edited. Guess I got confused by the names.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use the shifts in the other direction, use brackets as shift has low precedence.

```
compressed = (short) ((x << 12) | (y << 8) | z);
```